# Stream mining data source

Tags: javascript

when dealing with sensors in wireless sensor networks then sensors generate data. those data needs to be mined. In my problem I am going to use stream mining concepts. Stream mining means as an when data comes they mining process need to be happened. So my point here is it is not need to have a data source to mine and when sensors generate data we can do the mining and take a decision. Please correct me if I am wrong. thanks

Comment: I work in a related field (environmental monitoring networks) but still I hardly understand your question.

Comment: @ammoQ That's because there is no question.

Comment: @Brad Suddenly it all makes sense!

Comment: in a research project one need to analyze data in order to prove the concepts, in data mining one can find a data repository because we dealt with historic data analysis. But in stream mining we can not find such a data repository, So how can we deal with that in a such scenario